# Determine if two fields are equal

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to determine if one field (Approved) in one row in my table equals the Approved field in another row of the same table. There will always be only two records per each CommonId. I need to have a scalar return value of 1 indicating the two Approved fields are equal or a 0 indicating that the two Approved fields are not equal. Apparently I do not understand what the query is that I need.

Here is a representation of my table structure.

```
RecordId int
CommonId int
Approved bit
```

Records
In the two records below, I would like to get a 0 returned indicating that the Approved fields are not equal.

```
RecordId = 1
CommonId = 5
Approved = 1

RecordId = 2
CommonId = 5
Approved = 0
```

In the next two records below, I would like to get a 1 returned indicating that the Approved fields are equal.

```
RecordId = 3 
CommonId = 9
Approved = 1

RecordId = 4
CommonId = 9
Approved = 1
```

This is the query I've tried, but I get two rows and does not indicate if the two fields are equal.

```
SELECT A.Approved
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN MyTable B ON A.Approved = B.Approved
WHERE A.CommonId = 5
```

I tried using a GROUP BY to see if I could get just one row, but that does not work either.

```
SELECT Approved
FROM MyTable A
INNER JOIN MyTable B ON A.Approved = B.Approved
WHERE A.CommonId = 5
GROUP BY B.CommonId
```

Can someone show me the correct query to get what I want? Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain it a little better? Add a couple more example records and the expected output.

Comment: @FilipeSilva Added two more records and tried to clarify. See if that helps. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to join on the common ID ?

Comment: That is what I was trying, but could not get it to work. I have an answer below, so unless you want to offer a different solution, I have it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a `group by` would help?

```
select commonId,
       (case when max(Approved) = min(Approved) then 1 else 0 end) as IsEqual
from MyTable A
group by commonId;
```

This formulation assumes that the values are not `NULL` in the `approved` column (your question doesn't mention this as a possibility).

Comment: That works! Thank you very much. Not sure how it works and would have never thought of it. Do you have a link that can explain how it works?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are looking for correctly

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN (A.Approved = B.Approved) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM MyTable A,
MyTable B
WHERE A.commonId = B.commonId
```